# How to check LAMP is installed or not?

Tags: ssh

I am newbie in vps. I installed centos 6.5 64bit. one hour ago and installed Apache, php, mysql successfully. now I have to install phpmyadmin. It requires something called LAMP. I don't know if LAMP is already installed by default with centos or I have to manually install it. What is the ssh command to check it if LAMP installed or just answer yes or no.

UPDATE:
[understood]
That blogger confused me by separating LAMP with comma.
[image]

Comment: LAMP = Linux Apache Mysql PHP

Comment: I understand your confusion, but honestly it is sooo googlable.

Comment: please have a look @ update... I hit google with "how to check LAMP installed on cantos 6.5 or not". ha ha ha... You can't even think about this kind of question.

Comment: Just google "LAMP", first link is to wiki

Comment: my mind only focused on Lamp installed or not.. Even knowing the meaning of lamp didn't crossed in my mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If LAMP was correctly installed, i.e., PATH is already set for php,mysql and apache2, then run following commands from terminal:-

```
php -v  // Return PHP version

apache2 -v // Returns apache version

mysql --version // Returns mysql version
```

if all of the above command returns their respective versions, then it means LAMP is installed.

**BUT** if it doesn't then there might be two cases:-

1) LAMP might be installed but is not added to path.

2) LAMP is not installed, Install it.

As for the first case, if it is installed but not runnable from terminal, then just run following commands to see where LAMP components are installed:-

**1)** Find file with name "apache2" in your pc. It will return list of path where a file name called "apache2" exists. You can then cross examine it further.

```
sudo find / -name apache2
```

**2)** Run the above same command to find file "mysql" and follow the same procedure further.

```
sudo find / -name mysql
```

**3)** For PHP:-

```
sudo find / -name php
```

Answer (score 1):

LAMP stands for Linux, apache, Mysql, PHP, if you've installed apache, mysql and PHP correctly *on a linux system* you have LAMP already set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the above mentioned dependecies are installed or not

1. To check whether php is installed or not

php5 -v

2. For Apchae

/usr/sbin/apache2 -V

If any of the mentioned dependencies are not install and you want to install the LAMP use the following command,

sudo apt-get install lamp-server^